# django: how to make an attribute of a table be count of entries in another table

Tags: django, count

continuing the Django polls tutorial, I want an entry (I called it numChoices) in the Poll model that automatically updates with the number of Choices associated with that Poll. How can I do that?

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    numChoices = models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question
    def was_published_recently(self):
        now=timezone.now()
        return now-datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date < now
    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Clarification, the ideal use case would be such that:

If i just want to list all the polls with the number of choices associated with each poll, it won't have to query the Choice table.

But every time i add a choice, the poll entry associated with that choice will update it's numChoices count

Comment: clarification, the ideal use case would be such that:

-if i just want to list all the polls with the number of choices associated with each poll, it won't have to query the Choice table.

-but every time i add a choice, the poll entry associated with that choice will update it's numChoices count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want that. Just make it a property of the model instead.

```
class Poll(models.Model):
   ...
  @property
  def numChoices(self):
    return self.choice_set.count()
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it vitally important to have this information stored within the model? You can get a count of all related objects for a model simply by doing:

```
count = poll_object.choice_set.count()
```

Django automatically creates the "_set" (in this case choice_set) manager for you when you have a foreign key link between two models. By default the name of the related model will be a condensed version of the model name, so the model poll_choice's default related name would be "pollchoice_set". You can override the related name when you define the  FK field e.g.

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll, related_name="choices")
```

so now you would do

```
poll_object.choices.count()
```

to get the number of related choice objects.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in previous answers you can simple use @property, but it will cost you additional database hit everytime when you need choices count. For example, if you want to show all your Polls on a single page with choices count like this:

```
{% for poll in polls %}
    {{ poll.question }} - Choises: {{ poll.numChoices }}
{% endfor %}
```

It will hit database for every poll in a loop. So you will have 1 + COUNT(Polls.objects.all()) queries for that simple operation. Thats why you can store choices count in your model field and add another method to update choices count:

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    choices_count = models.IntegerField()  # To store num of choices.        

    def update_choices_count(self):
        self.choices_count = self.choice_set.count()
        self.save()
```

Once you create your poll and add some choices you can trigger update_choices_count. That's not critical for admin to generate some additional SQL queries while editing Polls, but critical for users to generate tons of additional database hits just for viewing Polls list.